# Spork Capybara, config.cache_classes conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, spork

I'm trying to setup Spork and Capybara with TestUnit, and am running 
into a test.rb config problem.

The issue is that Spork requires that 
config.cache_classes be set to false, so that changes in the model can 
be reflected when running tests without having to reset Spork all the 
time.

Capybara, on the other hand, seems to require that 
config.cache_classes be set to true, otherwise the integration tests 
just don't seem to work.

I'm just looking for any possible solution / explanation for this.  Is 
this something that only exists within TestUnit, or is this perhaps a 
bug and I should report it as such?  Any help would be greatly 
appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking an approach similar to [this](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/05/18/spork-rspec-sham-and-caching-classes/) one. The main thing you'll want to do is set your config.cache_classes to true, but force Spork to reload your models and dependencies on each run:

```
Spork.each_run do
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
end if Spork.using_spork?
```

Hopefully this will allow the cache_classes to be true for Capybara, but it will also allow your models and observers to be reloaded between test runs.

Comment: I've been searching all over for a solution to this problem, and all I see is comments that say "try this" and "do something like" and "hopefully". Unfortunately, this answer comes no closer to solving the problem than the others.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with spork and cucumber. The solution I found was :

```
config.cache_classes = (ENV['DRB'] == 'true' ? false : true)
```

spork sets the DRB environment. I dont think this is the most elegant way to solve this, but if capybara sets some env variable, you could use that ?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  cache_classes = false causes me great pains in other places when running the full test suite, but if I'm running spork, I'm usually task focused and adding debugs, etc.  Even with the each_run additions above, if cache_classes was set to true, spork just wouldn't reload for me.